# Python Dict - How to change Key name based on another dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have Python dict with keys and values. I want to rename/mapping the dict key based on another dict keys and values.
For example

```
data = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
```

my source data and mapping data is below.

```
key_changes ={'a': 'a1', 'b': 'b1'}
```

expected output is

```
{'a1': 1, 'b1': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
```

I tried to solve this issue using **for comprehension**. But I am getting Invalid syntax.

I have tried below solution

```
res = {
    key_chages[_key]:_value       
    else _key:_value
    for _key,_value in data.items()
    if _key in key_chages
    
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use dict comprehension to create a new dictionary.

```
res = { key_changes.get(key, key): value for key, value in data.items() }
```

`key_changes.get(key, key)` will make sure the keys are replaced and if not present use the current/original key.

Answer (score 0):

without rebuilding the whole dictionary, you can directly change the leys using the update method:

```
data.update(zip(key_changes.values(),map(data.pop,key_changes)))

print(data)
{'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'a1': 1, 'b1': 2}
```